# How would I constrain a regression model with two covariates so that the coefficient B2 is equal to 1/2B1?

Tags: linear-regression, constraints

If the original model is y = B0 + B1X1 + B2X2

How could I manipulate the equation or the data so that the coefficient B2 is equal to 1/2 B1?

y = B0 + B1X1 + 1/2B1X2

In theory, how could I do this with a real dataset?

Comment: Whoops, have edited thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite your model as
$y = B_0 + B_1 (X_1 + \frac{1}{2} X_2)$,
introduce a new variable $X_3 = X_1 + \frac{1}{2} X_2$,
and perform the regression on
$y = B_0 + B_1 X_3$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) Do you know of any resources where I can go to better understand why it is done like that?

Comment: Glad to help. Please mark my answer as accepted. Sorry, I don’t have any suggestion for specific resources.